# How to prevent gradient calculation for certain weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to that the gradient will not be calculated for certain weights or set to zero. As I do not want them to be updated during training.
Here is a code example:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
 import numpy as np

 tf.enable_eager_execution()


 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.sigmoid, input_shape=(2,)),
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.sigmoid)
 ])


 #set the weights
 weights=[np.array([[0, 0.25],     [0.2,0.3]]),np.array([0.35,0.35]),np.array([[0.4,0.5],[0.45, 0.55]]),np.array([0.6,0.6])]

 model.set_weights(weights)

 model.get_weights()

 features = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.05,0.10 ]])
 labels =  tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.01,0.99 ]])

 #define the loss function
 def loss(model, x, y):
   y_ = model(x)
   return tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=y_)

 #define the gradient calculation
 def grad(model, inputs, targets):
   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
     loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
   return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables) 

 #create optimizer an global Step
 optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
     global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
```

I want that the first weight which is 0 should not be included in the gradient calculation.
I found `tf.stop_gradient` and `tf.keras.backend.stop_gradient`. But do not know how and if you can apply them to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layer.trainable = False`  which will stop weights being changed in that layer during training.

To get the layers in your model you can call `model.layers` and pick the first or zeroth layer in the object you get back and then set trainable to false, something like :

```
      layers =  model.layers
      layers[0].trainable = False
```

Comment: I just want the Zero to be untrainable the other weights in this layer should be trained. Does your answer cover that? When I tried to set the layer untrainable all the weights in this layer will not be trained.